# Archive old data in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have a huge MongoDB database powered by mongoengine where the objects have a date. To make work easier, I want to archive old objects but keep them somewhere.

I've been reading the documentation and came across `switch_db` and `switch_collection`. However, I can't make either work.

For both cases, the documentation references two usage scenarios.

1. As a `QuerySet` operation:

   ```
   user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
   user.switch_collection('old-users')
   user.save()
   ```

   The problem with this is it only works for an individual object. It is not possible to batch archive multiple documents.
2. As a `context_manager`:

   ```
   with switch_collection(Group, 'group1') as Group:
   Group(name="hello testdb!").save()  # Saves in group1 collection
   ```

   Using this I can't even make the query, getting the following error:

   ```
   ValidationError (Document:None) (Field is required...
   ```

I've tried searching for a way to archive data with mongoengine, but none of the options seem to work. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: try put: `from models import Doc` into your archive script

Comment: Thanks, after fixing that error I get a new one, I guess I need to connect to a new db but didn't find anything about this in the docs.

Comment: You have tried to test if the line connect('doc-archive') is successfully reaching to mongodb?

Comment: @VictorH.Panisa how can I test that?

Comment: @liarspocker see the API doc, http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#api-reference

you probably don't registered the connection alias, see mongoengine.register_connection for details

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the MongoDB instance itself, why not just run a query directly against that, instead of jumping thru the hoops of MongoEngine?

you can rename your current `users` collection to `users-old` using this command:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/

and then run a simple script to copy the newer values over to a new `users` collection